# NodeRedis client.multi() hgetall performance

Tags: node.js, redis, node-redis

node version: v7.4.0

node-redis version: v.2.6.2

redis_version:2.8.4

ubuntu 14.04 2GB RAM VPS instance

I'm getting indications that node_redis hgetall performance isn't what it should be, but possibly I'm doing something wrong. I have a sorted set with 31669 elements. The elements are hash keys and each hash has 14 fields and is ~256 bytes. Retrieving the hashes takes ~64 seconds which seems too slow.
Here is what the function looks like:

```
function getAllAnnotations()
{
var currentSeconds = Math.floor((new Date()).getTime() / 1000);
console.log('currentSeconds before zrange: ' + currentSeconds);

    client.zrangebyscore("geoHashSortedSet", "-inf", "+inf", function(err, reply) {

        multi = client.multi();
        for (var uuid in reply) {
            multi.hgetall(reply[uuid]);

        }
        multi.exec(function(err, replies) {

            var currentSeconds = Math.floor((new Date()).getTime() / 1000);
            console.log('currentSeconds after multi returns: ' + currentSeconds);
            allAnnotations = replies;
        });

    });

}
```

Do others here agree that this is poor performance, and is there anything I'm doing in the code above that is part of the issue?

Comment: Have you tried [`client.batch()`](https://github.com/NodeRedis/node_redis#clientbatchcommands)? You're also not just timing the batch, but `zrangebyscore` as well.

Comment: I will try client.batch().  And yes I was aware that I was timing zrangebyscore.  Probably I should not include it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You are timing the `zrangebyscore` as well and you are using `-inf` to `+inf` which means the entire elements. Why note use `zrange` instead with `0` and `-1`. That could be faster.

Try this

```
function getAllAnnotations()
{
    var start = Date.now();

    client.zrange("geoHashSortedSet", 0, -1, function(err, reply) {
        console.log('zrange took ', Date.now() - start);
        start = Date.now();

        multi = client.multi();
        reply.forEach(function(id) {
            multi.hgetall(id);
        });
        multi.exec(function(err, replies) {

            console.log('multi took', Date.now() - start);
            allAnnotations = replies;
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: I want the entire elements, also I was thinking that the zrangebyscore time would be fairly insignificant so that is why I originally included it.  I compared zrange to zrangebyscore and they run in about the same time from redis-cli.   Thanks, but the answer I got from the node-redis maintainer.

Answer (score 0):

The answer came from the NodeRedis maintainer:

You are very likely using a older redis-parser version that still had issues with big nested arrays. The implementation had a flaw that was overlooked in the beginning.

Your issue is going away as soon as you update your dependencies. As a side note: by using batch instead of multi your performance should again go up if you do not have the necessity for having a transaction.

Overall your call should not take long with that change.

ref: https://github.com/NodeRedis/node_redis/issues/1225

The redis-parser version I was using was  v.2.0.3 - 17 Jun, 2016.  Updating to v.2.6.0 - 03 Apr, 2017 fixed the issue as my time went down to ~2 seconds from ~64 seconds